# How to get the Histogram based on the intensity cross section of each spot?

Tags: image-processing, histograms

I am supposed to plot the histogram based on the intensity cross-section of each circular area, I have done counting manually each area based on the pixel intensity cross-section of each green and red spot, is there any way to count them without manually counting?
I have tried this:
1: separate the green colour from red,
2: I did component measurements for mean intensity for each image
3: plot histogram
Although I think my procedure is not correct to reach the histogram in the format I have attached.

```
img = Import[] ;
id = ImageData[pic]
ImageChannels[pic];
dat = Map[If[Total[#[[1 ;; 3]]] < 0.6, #, 0 #] &, id, {2}];
image3 = Image[dat]
dat2 = Map[If[Total[#[[1 ;; 3]]] > 0.6, #, 0 #] &, id, {2}];
image4 = Image[dat2]
I1 = ComponentMeasurements[image3, "MeanIntensity"]
I2 = ComponentMeasurements[image4, "MeanIntensity"]
Histogram[{I1, I2}]
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks, As I am trying the plot the histogram for the intensity count of each green and red spot @RudyPotter

Comment: OK great, I think my second answer might do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import picture to Mathematica.
2. Find each individual spot brightness and color
3. Make histogram of brightness for each color

Import picture and change to Hue Saturation Brightness (HSB) color space:

```
pic = Import["C:\\some_path\\XY3IB.png"]
HSBpic = ColorConvert[pic, "HSB"]
```

Find the red spots where total intensity >1 and and median HSB value is between 0 and 0.1:

```
redSpots = 
 ComponentMeasurements[HSBpic, {"Image", "TotalIntensity", "Median"}, 
  0 < #Median[[1]] < .1 && #TotalIntensity > 1 &]
```

Find the green spots where total intensity >1 and and median HSV value is between 0.25 and 0.42:

```
greenSpots = 
 ComponentMeasurements[
  HSBpic, {"Image", "TotalIntensity", 
   "Median"}, .25 < #Median[[1]] < .42 && #TotalIntensity > 1 &]
```

Histogram of total intensities for each spot color:

```
Histogram[{Values[redSpots][[;; , 2]], 
  Values[greenSpots][[;; , 2]]}, {1}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am wondering to know how you put the median HSV value? This procedure is quite fine but not working in may case -@Rudy Potter

Comment: #Median gets the median value of the color vectors.  We converted to HSB color space first and so #Median[[1]]  should be the median hue.

Comment: HSV was a typo, I should have said HSB, fixed in answer.